# How to have custom ajax commands on element using InvokeCommand

Tags: 8, ajax

How can i use custom ajax command using #ajax api , i have the following code working well

```
        $ajax_response = new AjaxResponse();                
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-event-trigger', 'attr', array('disabled',true)));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-event-trigger', 'removeAttr', array('placeholder')));
        $ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-event-trigger', 'css',array("background-color", "")));
        //Return the AjaxResponse Object.
        return $ajax_response;
```

But suppose if i want to **`focus()`** or **`hide()`** the **`edit-event-trigger`** element , how could i do that ?

Comment: did you try `'focus'` and `'hide'`?

Comment: tried like this : **$ajax_response->addCommand(new InvokeCommand('#edit-event-trigger', 'focus'));**

Comment: This is ok, did you check for php errors, could be a missing use statement?

Comment: yes i checked , am using the following ajax classes : **use Drupal\Core\Ajax\ChangedCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\CssCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\AjaxResponse;
use Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand;**

Comment: I think there is nothing wrong with your ajax commands. They should work.

Comment: Thanks , i was given the code in wrong handler ;) . it worked .

Comment: How do I set or unset a value with `InvokeCommand` . I tried with the following but no luck.

    `$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand('.field--t input', 'set', array('field_tt', 'myvalue')));`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are some examples you can try:

```
$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand('.message', 'addClass', array('show')));
$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand('.message', 'removeClass', array('show')));
$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand('.message', 'attr', array('value', '123')));
$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\HtmlCommand('.message', "Show this text"));
$response->addCommand(new \Drupal\Core\Ajax\InvokeCommand('.message', 'css', array('background', '#dff0d8')));
```

Peace.